# Change the property "DefaultValue" of the asp.net "ControlParameter" control with javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, properties

I already have an idea on how to do this, but I realized that the control "ControlParameter" did not have an "Id" property (which is needed for the JS). Is there a different way to use JavaScript to change the "DefaultValue" property without the need of using the "Id" property?

Here is the JavaScript and asp.net code that I have been working with:

JavaScript:

```
        function ChangePropertyValue(propertyName, newpropertyValue) {
        var ControlParameter = document.getElementById(propertyName)
        ControlParameter.DefaultValue = newpropertyValue
    }
```

asp.net:

```
        <asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" Text="try" OnClick="ChangePropertyValue(??, 17)"/>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [ContentTitle], [Content] FROM [Table1] WHERE ([Id] = @Id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" DefaultValue="16" Name="Id" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a `ControlParameter` client side. `ControlParameters` are used to bind the value of a Control property server side, they are not rendered to the client. You can, however, set the Default value of the `ControlParameter` programmatically in your Code Behind.

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["id"].DefaultValue = "value";
```

Comment: Now is there a way to change the code behind with a button control?
(As in the DefaultValue)