# Change C# code with multiple button controls

Tags: asp.net, button

I would like to know if it is possible to change the code "DefaultValue" in the C# file that is used by "example.aspx" by using a few button controls.

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["id"].DefaultValue = "value";
```

As you can see I already have part of what I need. I would just like to be able to insert different numbers (e.g. 14) into where it says "value" according to different buttons. If you dont understand what I am trying to say please refer to:
[Change the property “DefaultValue” of the asp.net “ControlParameter” control with javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775492/change-the-property-defaultvalue-of-the-asp-net-controlparameter-control-with)

Comment: Where exactly do you want to change the value? The code you provided is the for datasource. You can definitely change that value on postback and do a rebind of whatever data control it is binded to. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not really sure of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a SqlDataSource with ControlParameter that has a property "DefaultValue". I would like to change whatever the value of the DefaultValue is to another value (e.g. 74) with a button control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASPX File:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Value1" onclick="Button_Click" 
            CommandArgument="value1" />

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Value2" onclick="Button_Click" 
            CommandArgument="value2" />
```

CodeBehind (C#):

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["id"].DefaultValue = button.CommandArgument;

    // Your other codes for e.g. databinding....
}
```