# ASP .Net UpdatePanel Audio Player

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got two Dropdownlist and one Jplayer in UpdatePanel of asp page.  Dropdownlist getting updated fine but Jplayer not.  Please can anyone help that what I am missing.  I tried looking for answer everywhere but didn't find any.

Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table style="width: 100%">                                
    <tr>                        
    <td style="width: 800px; text-align: center;">  
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
       </asp:ScriptManager>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>                          
          <br />                         
            <div class="s4">Select Translation</div>                                                                     
               <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource6" DataTextField="TranslationLang" DataValueField="TranslationLang" Height="25px" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>                             
               <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource6" runat="server" DataFile="Database/HF.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [TranslationLang] FROM [Translation]">
               </asp:AccessDataSource>                               
               <br />
               <br />
               <div class="s4">Select Surah (Quran Chapter)</div>
               <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList2" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource7" DataTextField="Surah" DataValueField="Surah" Height="25px" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
               <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource7" runat="server" DataFile="Database/HF.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [Surah] FROM [TranslationSurah] WHERE ([Lang] = ?) ORDER BY [No]">
               <SelectParameters>
               <asp:controlparameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Lang" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
               </SelectParameters>
               </asp:AccessDataSource>                                
               <br />
               <br />
               <script type="text/javascript">                 
                   $(document).ready(function(){            
                    var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
                    {
                       m4a: "Quran/" + document.getElementById("DropDownList1").value +  "/" + document.getElementById("DropDownList2").value
                    }, {
                       cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
                       swfPath: "Scripts/MMPlayer/MMPlayerJS",
                       wmode: "window"
                    });
                   });
            </script>
               </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <!-------------------------------------------------Player-----------------------------------------------------------> 
          <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="cp-jplayer"></div>
            <div id="cp_container_1" class="cp-container">
            <div class="cp-buffer-holder">
          <div class="cp-buffer-1"></div>
            <div class="cp-buffer-2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="cp-progress-holder"> 
            <div class="cp-progress-1"></div>
            <div class="cp-progress-2"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="cp-circle-control"></div>
            <ul class="cp-controls">
                <li><a class="cp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                <li><a class="cp-pause" style="display:none;" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div> 
          <!-------------------------------------------------Player-----------------------------------------------------------> 

          <br />                   
    </td>                    
    </tr>                   
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You **can't** access a ControlParameter client side. ControlParameters are used to bind the value of a Control property server side, they are not rendered to the client. You can, however, set the Default value of the ControlParameter programmatically in your Code Behind. [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1775773/1322642)

Comment: So how can i embed/use this code in my code?